# TripleDES decryption in python

Tags: python, c#, encryption

I'm trying to convert the following c# function to python

the orginal C# function

```
public static string Decrypt(string Key, string toDecrypt) // key.length = 16 Byte
{
    if (Key != "") {
        try {
            byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
            byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key);
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
                toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        } catch {
            return "";
        }
    } else
        return "";
}
```

that's my try in python

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

mac='OtTL6k9yLn6VJIZRXRj1OA=='
key='nOwy4iuE8c8WcktG'

toEncryptArray = base64.b64encode(mac.encode('utf-8'))
keyArray = key.encode('utf-8')
print(DES3.adjust_key_parity(keyArray))

cipher = DES3.new(keyArray, DES3.MODE_ECB)
decriptText = cipher.decrypt(toEncryptArray)
print(decriptText)
```

the result that i get in python is not equal to the c# result

Comment: Can you show what the output from your C# and Python programs are?

Comment: c# output = K5Hp3L0ATnGOdJ8I
python output = b'\xe55\xe1\xc2\x1aJ\\\x0c!eC2\x8c\xf3\xd3a\x7f`8\xfe\xeb\xf7.\xb5W"\xdbA\x8d\xf7\x06\x9d'

Comment: The ciphertext obviously has to be Base64 **de**coded: `toEncryptArray = base64.b64decode(mac)` (and not `toEncryptArray = base64.b64encode(mac.encode('utf-8'))`. Then the plaintext of the C# code results: `K5Hp3L0ATnGOdJ8I`.

Comment: @Topaco you right, now its work for me